# How do you return a specific row per group by some criteria in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, partition-by

I have a table of people with `firstname`, `surname`, and `age`. I would like to retrieve the oldest person in each family (by `surname`). I don't want to just return the `surname` and `age` (via `MAX(age)` and `GROUP BY surname`) I want the entire row.

For example if my data is:

```
firstname, surname, age
john, smith, 31
sally, smith, 33
bob, smith, 34
john wayne, 35
bob wayne, 31
```

I would like my query to return:

```
firstname, surname, age
bob, smith, 34
john wayne, 35
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select surname, array_agg(struct(firstname, age) order by age desc limit 1)[offset(0)].*
from your_table
group by surname
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: glad it worked for you. please consider also voting up the answer if it helped